# How to check, that page is autoscrolled to appropriate block?

Tags: java, selenium

On the site, which Im testing, we have the navigate menu. 
I want to create the test, which will click on the element in navigate in menu and check, that screen is scrolled to appropriate block.
I have tried to use findElement, but it finding on whole page, no on the screen size only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the plain javascript that will check if the element is in the current viewport and returns true/false.

```
function isElementInViewport(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return  rect.bottom > 0 &&
            rect.right > 0 &&
            rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
            rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) ;
}
```

**First we will see how this works in browser console.**

- Open the dev tools (short key ctrl+shift+I)
- Copy paste the above javascript function in console tab
- Hit Enter
- Now check if `Questions` element is showing in the view port on the current page by running the following line

  > console.log(isElementInViewport(document.querySelector("li.-item a[href='/questions']")));
- You should see `false` in the console output
- Now scroll down all the way down in this page
- Run the same above line

  > console.log(isElementInViewport(document.querySelector("li.-item 
  >   a[href='/questions']")));
- This time you should see `true` in the console output as the element is visible in the viewport.

**Now let's see how to use this in Selenium:**

```
    // navigate to stackoverflow page
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
    /* below is the javascript function that we have to run in the browser console
     * If you look at the starting of the function name declaration in the javascript you see the difference
     * `window.functioName = function(arg)` is the general notation when you 
     * want to make the javscript function available in the browser window
     */

    String jsFunction = "window.isElementInViewport= function(el) {\r\n" + 
            "    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();\r\n" + 
            "    return  rect.bottom > 0 &&\r\n" + 
            "            rect.right > 0 &&\r\n" + 
            "            rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&\r\n" + 
            "            rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) ;\r\n" + 
            "}";
    // execute the javascript function
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript(jsFunction);

    // Questions Element
    WebElement questionsEle = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.-item a[href='\\/questions']"));

    // check Questions Elements before scrolling
    System.out.println(js.executeScript("return isElementInViewport(arguments[0])", questionsEle));

    // Scroll to element
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", questionsEle);

    // check Questions Elements after scrolling
    System.out.println(js.executeScript("return isElementInViewport(arguments[0])", questionsEle));
```

That's all now you can port this simple solution to your issue.

Comment: Excellent idea to create function and then check it in chrome inspector. The only thing I would add is to separate out your java-script code into a utility class eg PageScroll and putting all your javascript scrolling operations there, that way you can reuse it.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, but I need the resolution in Java, not js :)

Comment: Don't you want to use the JS call to verify from Java? If you want it in pure Java/Selenium, Then you can get the location of the element, and do the calculation as I implemented in the js.